# Sass get current class without parent

Tags: css, sass

```
.site-header
    .basket
        position: relative
        &-container
            width: 100%
            padding: 0 18px
        $basket: &
        &.opened
            #{$basket}-link
                border: 1px solid #e5e5e5
                border-bottom: 1px solid white
            #{$basket}-wrapper
                visibility: visible
                opacity: 1
```

I want to add to basket opened state.

I need to output .site-header .basket.opened .basket-wrapper

But outputing .site-header .basket.opened .site-header .basket-wrapper

& contains .site-header. How do i correctly remove from it? So $basket will have current class

http://sass.js.org/

I just wanted to not write basket often

```
.site-header
    .basket
        position: relative
        .basket-container
            width: 100%
            padding: 0 18px
        .basket.opened
            .basket-link
                border: 1px solid #e5e5e5
                border-bottom: 1px solid white
            .basket-wrapper
                visibility: visible
                opacity: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this variant:

```
.basket
    $basket: &
    .site-header &
        position: relative
        &-container
            width: 100%
            padding: 0 18px
        &.opened
            #{$basket}-link
                border: 1px solid #e5e5e5
                border-bottom: 1px solid white
            #{$basket}-wrapper
                visibility: visible
                opacity: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of the question is get-cur-class()

```
@function str-split($string, $separator)
    $split-arr: ()
    $index : str-index($string, $separator)
    @while $index != null
        $item: str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1)
        $split-arr: append($split-arr, $item)
        $string: str-slice($string, $index + 1)
        $index : str-index($string, $separator)

    $split-arr: append($split-arr, $string)

    @return $split-arr

@function last($list) 
    @return nth($list, length($list))

@function get-cur-class()
    $path-arr: str-split('"' + & + '"',' ')
    @return last($path-arr)

.site-header
    .basket
        position: relative
        &-container
            width: 100%
            padding: 0 18px
        $t: get-cur-class()
        &.opened
            #{$t}-link
                border: 1px solid #e5e5e5
                border-bottom: 1px solid white
            #{$t}-wrapper
                visibility: visible
                opacity: 1
```